# NgStyle in Angular 7 CSS grid layout not working properly?

Tags: css, angular7, ng-style

I am having a problem with ngStyle after updating to angular 7. In angular 5 its working fine.

Using ngStyle I am dynamically applying style with Css grid.

but dont know why 'grid-column': '1 / span 2' is not working.

here is my code

```
<div class="widthHeight100"
     [ngStyle]="getStyleForGroup(group)">
  <div *ngFor="let subGroup of group?.childs"
       [ngStyle]="getStyleForSubGroup(subGroup)">
```

In typescript

Grid container:

```
  getStyleForGroup(mdg: MdgSimple) {
let style: any = {
  'width': '100%',
  'height': '100%'
};
if (!isNullOrUndefined(mdg)) {
  if (!isNullOrUndefined(mdg.childs)) {
    if (mdg.childs.length > 0) {
      style = {
        'display': 'grid',
        'grid-template-rows': this.getGridTemplateCount(mdg.childs, true),
        'grid-template-columns': this.getGridTemplateCount(mdg.childs, false),
        'grid-column-gap': '4px',
        'grid-row-gap': '4px',
        'justify-items': 'start',
        'align-items': 'start',
        'padding': '5px'
      };
    }
  }
}
return style;
```

}

Childs:

```
  getStyleForSubGroup(mdsg: MdsgSimple) {
let style: any = {
  'width': '100%',
  'height': '100%'
};
if (!isNullOrUndefined(mdsg) && !isNullOrUndefined(mdsg.layout)) {
  style = {
    'grid-row': this.getCssRowInfo(mdsg),
    'grid-column': this.getCssColumnInfo(mdsg),

    'height': this.getHeight(mdsg),
    'width': this.getWidth(mdsg),
    'min-width': this.getMinWidth(mdsg),
    'max-width': this.getMaxWidth(mdsg),
    'min-height': this.getMinHeight(mdsg),
    'max-height': this.getMaxHeight(mdsg),
  };
}
return style;
```

}

But controls are overlapping each other. I have checked using chrome css element inspector grid area showing unsafe.

But its all working fine in angular 5 version.
example **1 / span 2** also not working

here is screen shot for error.
[image]

Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the exact same issue. ngStyle is replacing this:
 `{
      'grid-column': (width > 1 ? column + ' / ' + (column + width) : column + ''),
      'grid-row': '' + row
     }`
with this:
    `style="grid-area: 1 / unsafe / auto / unsafe`
when width > 1

Comment: Did you find solution ? I am still searching for solution.  Angular 5 its working fine

Comment: I used this instead:  `{
      'grid-column-start': column,
      'grid-column-end': (column + width),
      'grid-row': row
    }` and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks its working now. main problem is the Angular dom sensitization

Comment: how is this the answer? this just illustrates the problem

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<p [ngStyle]="myStyles">
    Hello World!
</p>
```

TS

```
myStyles = {
    'color': 'red',
    'font-size': '20px',
    'font-weight': 'bold'
}
```

I just write very basic code, Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

Comment: above code works. But my code is different.  Its works fine in Angular5 not in 7

Comment: Please share what error are you facing. Because I verify this code in my Angular7 app.

Comment: I am not getting any error. But controls are overlapping like in screen shot. When I inspect the elements using chrome debugger, the grid-area showing unsafe.

Comment: Please share fiddle for the overlapping issue, because it’s difficult to verify CSS related issue in screenshot. Thanks

Comment: This grid property seems to be interprated differently by angular https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28897.  Personally, the fix i found was to list possibilities and dynamically assigned the class to the element: 
.app-scroller-spread-row-4 { grid-column: 1 / 6;  }.app-scroller-spread-row-5 { grid-column: 1 / 7;}